# ADO NET Source Error SSIS On Package Execurion

Tags: sql, mysql, database, ssis, etl

Hi Guys i am having a problem with loading data from a on-premises MYSQL DB to an on-premises SQL DB using SSIS maybe someone can point me in the correct direction on how to solve the problem the DB's reside on different server.

The errors are as follows.

Error: The buffer manager could not get a temporary file name.
Warning: The buffer manager could not create a temporary file on the path "Z:\New folder\SSISBlobTempStorage". The path will not be considered for temporary storage again.

[ADO NET Source tbl Guest [2]] Error: The error "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component." occurred while processing "ADO NET Source tbl Guest.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output].Columns[userAgent]".

[ADO NET Source tbl Guest [2]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "ADO NET Source tbl Guest" failed because error code 0x80004005 occurred, and the error row disposition on "ADO NET Source tbl Guest.Outputs[ADO NET Source Output].Columns[userAgent]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

[ADO NET Source tbl Guest [2]] Error: The ADO NET Source tbl Guest was unable to process the data. Pipeline component has returned HRESULT error code 0xC0209029 from a method call.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ADO NET Source tbl Guest returned error code 0xC02090F5.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

example of the data stored in the column would be:
{"agent.device":"iPhone","agent.tablet":false,"agent.mobile":true,"agent.desktop":false,"agent.feature":false,"agent.platform.name":"AndroidOS","agent.platform.version":"4.0","agent.browser.name":"Safari","agent.browser.version":"537","agent.robot":false...

datatype for the ADO NET source is Unicode Text Stream
datatype for the OLE DB destination is also Unicode Text Stream

Can someone maybe point me in the correct direction to resolve these errors ?

For the buffer error i have treid deleting the .vs file to resolve the error and that did not work.

For the row disposition error i have tried the methods suggested in other posts to resolve the error and no luck.